# char *word; printf(" %s", word) Issues

Tags: c, printf

1st post on StackOverflow so I apologize if I didn't make it good. I'm stuck on a dumb exercise where I need to make an "hangman game" I try to read word from a ".txt" file and then I have got my crypting function which replace each letters by a `'*'` and put an `'\0'` at the `lenght+1` position to end the string.

I got issues to get the size of my `char*` and my biggest problem is that i can't display it correctly on the console, I only get strange symbols printed.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void pendu()
{
    FILE *fichier = NULL;
    fichier = fopen("dico.txt", "r");
    if (fichier == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erreur ouverture du fichier");
    }
    int taille = get_size("dico.txt");

    int nb;
    srand(time(NULL));
    nb = rand() % taille;

    char *momo = get_word(nb, fichier);

    printf("Vous allez jouer au pendu! \n");
    printf("Voici le mot a trouver : \n");
    int longueur = sizeof(momo); // i know size of return size in byte so may i
    //do sizeof(word)/sizeof(char) ?

    char *motcrypt = cryptage(momo,longueur);

    printf(" %s \n", motcrypt); // here is the main Problem.
    int tour = 10;
    while (tour > 0)
    {
        char lettre;

        printf(" %s \n", motcrypt);
        printf("il vous reste %d tour(s) \n", tour);

        printf("proposer une lettre :", tour);

        scanf(" %c", &lettre); // space needed !!?!!

        printf("\n");
        char *motcrypt2 = motcrypt;
        for (int i = 0; i < longueur; i++)
        {
            if (lettre == momo[i])
            {
                motcrypt2[i] = lettre;
            }
        }
        if (motcrypt == motcrypt2)
        {
            tour = tour-1;
            printf("%s", motcrypt);
        }
        if (motcrypt2 == momo)
        {
            motcrypt = motcrypt2;
            printf("%s", motcrypt);
            printf("Vous avez gagner! \n");
            printf("Appuyer sur un bouton pour rejouer \n");        
            system("Pause");

        }
        else if (tour == 0)
        {
            printf("Vous avez perdu\n");
            printf("Appuyer sur un bouton pour rejouer \n");
            system("Pause");
            pendu();
        }
    }

}

void main()
{
    pendu();
}
```

Edit: here is my "cryptage" function:

```
char* cryptage(char *yala,int x)
{
    int i = 0;
    char crypted[30];
    while (i < x)
    {
        crypted[i] = '*';
        crypted[i + 1] = '\0';
        i++;        
    }
    return crypted;
}
```

I got my crypting function which replace each letters by a '*' and put an '\0' at the lenght+1 position to end the string.

PS : i would love someone to explain me why `printf("%s",word)` don't have the same output than `printf(" %s",word)`

Comment: You can't use `sizeof` on a pointer to figure out the size of the thing it's pointing at. Even less so for variable-length things like C strings, that's why we have `strlen()` but that of course requires the termination to already be there. You should use string-oriented I/O, i.e. `fgets()`, that will terminate the string for you.

Comment: @unwind You comment deserves being promoted to an actual answer.

Comment: `cryptage` isn't a standard function is it? Where is it defined?

Comment: Nope, i juste added it by edit, srry i didn't do it before, but i really debugged and saw that she worked fine (building an string of size x ending with '\0')

Comment: You dont compare char* for equality using ==. This only compares the pointers. If you do     char *motcrypt2 = motcrypt;, then motcrypt2 points to the same memory as motcrypt. Thus even a strcmp(motcrypt2, motcrypt) would always return 0 (equal). You need own storage for motcrypt2 either on the stack (e.g. char motcrypt2[1024]; or using new like char *motcrypt=new char[...]). then strcpy(motcrypt2, motcrypt).

Comment: Your function `cryptage` is **not** debugged!. You don't use `*yala` and `char crypted[30]` goes out of scope when you return from the function - but you return its pointer which is used by the caller.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. A working example would have been nice.

Comment: Use `strlen(momo);` instead of `sizeof(momo);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, but let's start with your `cryptage` function:

```
char* cryptage(char *yala,int x)
{
int i = 0;
char crypted[30];
while (i < x)
{
    crypted[i] = '*';
    crypted[i + 1] = '\0';
    i++;        
}
return crypted;
}
```

Other than the bad indentation, you are returning a pointer to an array with automatic storage duration which goes out of scope when the function returns. Using that pointer will result in undefined behaviour (including potentially a crash or strange output, or, occasionally, *appearing* to work correctly). You should either allocate the storage for `crypted` dynamic (look up `malloc`) or instead accept a pointer to it as a parameter:

```
char* cryptage(char *yala, int x, char *crypted)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < x)
    {
        crypted[i] = '*';
        crypted[i + 1] = '\0';
        i++;        
    }
    return crypted;
}
```

This line:

```
int longueur = sizeof(momo); // i know size of return size in byte so may i
```

... is presumably meant to obtain the length of the string pointed at by `momo` rather than the size of the pointer itself. It should therefore read:

```
size_t longueur = strlen(momo); // i know size of return size in byte so may i
```

Several `if` statements appear to be trying to compare strings:

```
    if (motcrypt == motcrypt2)
```

... but this is comparing pointers, not the string contents. You need to use the `strcmp` function:

```
    if (strcmp(motcrypt,motcrypt2) == 0)
```

You haven't shown definitions of various other methods so it's impossible to give you a complete list of problems. When you post to StackOverflow, you should post a *complete* (but *minimal*) example which exhibits the problem (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Extra +1 for the MCVE link.

Comment: thank you for your respond i think i have all the element i need to fix my code

Answer (score 1):

```
warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 return crypted;
 ^
```

This is what I immediately get as a warning when I try to compile this code (after filling in the missing functions).

You are trying to return the address of a variable based on the stack. Two lines later when you call printf, it overwrites the area where `crypted` was stored.

Allocate memory from the heap (see: [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)) and return that address. Don't forget to [free](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) it after printing.

Comment: thanks for respond i'm not familiar with c and malloc, i'll document myself and try it out :)